# Label causing Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, objective-c, label, signals, sigabrt

I recently made a new view controller in my project and I added a label and attached the label to a outlet i made in the .h

```
IBOutlet UILabel *coinAmount;
```

I did this. Thats all I did no code in side the .m file and I linked it up to the label in the view controller and when I click on a button to open the view controller it gives me a signal SIGABRT. So I deleted the label and it worked perfectly! I don't know why this is happening.

Things I tried :

1 - Changing name of outlet

2 - Creating new view controller

3 - Creating new .h and .m

4 - Deleting label and using another label

5 - Shutting down computer coming back

---

Well thats as far as my knowledge goes. :D 
Please help me with the hair pulling problem!

Thanks for all the people who take the time to help me in this very annoying problem. Sorry if this is easy to you. I am very new.

```
    2014-10-19 21:29:06.963 Speedy[1462:35954] Unknown class clab in Interface Builder file.
2014-10-19 21:29:06.968 Speedy[1462:35954] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7fed8ac9d9f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001054db3f5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104dcbbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001054db039 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001049694d3 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105425400 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000105dcd97d -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000105c2e698 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000105c2ec88 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000105c2eef9 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000105c2f38e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001061cc83f -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 65
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000105c0ac49 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 105
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000105c3b121 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 1746
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000105c3d461 __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 132
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000105c3d385 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 229
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000105b0b9ee -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000105c11bd0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000105c10f9f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000105b513b8 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000105b51ce3 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000105b1eae1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000105b2bbad _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000105b07233 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105410ad1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010540699d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105405fd4 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105405a06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001075339f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    28  UIKit                               0x0000000105b0a550 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    29  Speedy                              0x000000010488a2d3 main + 115
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001088d1145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack trace (and things like SIGABRT) is always a terrifying error for new coders, but the real error is actually shown at the top, in the first few lines: `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key`**`label`**

The most likely explanation is that you had a `UILabel` connected to an object in your Storyboard which was called `label`. Later on, you changed the name of this property to `coinAmount`, as shown in the code that you gave.

When you change the name of a property, this does not automatically update the connection in your Storyboard. Instead, what happens is that the new `coinAmount` property ends up not being linked to anything, and your Storyboard has a label linked to a property called `label` that doesn't exist in your class - hence the crash for trying to set an undefined property.

#### The solution?

Look through your Storyboard for the UILabel that you're referring to. Select it, and select the last tab ("Connections inspector") in the panel on the right, where your connections to other objects/views are displayed. You should have a "Referencing Outlet" called `label` here. Remove it.

Add a new referencing outlet to the parent view controller (drag the outlined circle to the view controller at the very top of the hierarchy on the left) and a popup should appear containing `coinAmount` - select this, and you're done!